# Unable to filter multidimensional array using array_filter in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to filter a data using PHP. I'm able to filter using the key when there is only one key in the params. If there are multiple keys i get the value only for the last param.

Ex: In the request URL if the `City=NY& Category=Population` I get a proper value. When I add another param with same key i.e `City=NY&Category=Population&City=SF` I get the value for only SF where it should give me the sum of both NY and SF. The data is being pulled from a table.

My code is :

```
function search(array $array, array $search)
{

return array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($search) {

//print_r(array_intersect_assoc($search, $item));
print_r($item);
return array_intersect_assoc($search, $item) === $search;

});
}

$filteredarray = search($json_output, $query);
```

Comment: If you want to have more than one `City` in your query string, you should use `City[]=NY&City[]=SF`. Otherwise, the last parameter overrides the previous ones.

Comment: Agreed with @Syscall. Better to use `POST` mechanism with array data sending.